# AngularJS Cannot read property 'path' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, routes, location

what I am trying to do is to get to other page if my vm.Question is empty but it dose not work, here is my work

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular.module('mainApp').controller('question-template', ['dataContext', function (dataContext, $location) {
    var vm = this;

    dataContext.getOneQuestion(sessionStorage.getItem("SavedString")).then(
        function (response) {
            vm.Question = response.data;
            if (vm.Question.length == 0) {
                $location.path("/noquestion"); <- HERE
                return;                 
            }
        },
        function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
     }]);
})();
```

Any help would be awesome, thank you

Comment: you didn't inject it correctly: `['dataContext', function (dataContext, $location)`, add `'$location'`

Comment: it worked! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `$location` in Dependency Annotation, line 3rd:

`angular.module('mainApp').controller('question-template', ['dataContext', '$location', function (dataContext, $location) {`